# Making a layer mask with 2 layers in Photoshop cc

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

http://vimeo.com/79253462

Plz watch this video from 6:00~6:22 !
I wanted to make an ios7's transparent navigation bar, so i found this video. 
In the video, he made a shape mask with only dragging the shape layer to another layer. I couldn't do the same thing as him with my computer, I tried to do that though. When i kept pressing 'alt' and dragged a shape layer to another one, it didn't work at all. It was only duplicated itself. Then, how can i make a linked layer or a shape layer like in the video?

Comment: You say you were pressing `alt`... but you need to (as the video says) hold `cmd` and `alt` ...is that what you did?

Comment: Wow thank you... I probably missed that direction !

Answer (score 2):

On a PC, before clicking on the shape mask you need to hit the Ctrl+Alt, and then drag the shape onto the layer you want to mask.

On Mac, it's Command+Option key, and then drag the shape layer onto the one you want to mask.

Source: http://veerle.duoh.com/design/article/photoshop_layers_tricks_and_shortcuts